# Is it possible to allow a user to access a dir without making him the owner?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

For my desktop machine, I'd like to be able to access files in my home directory in a browser.

I have set the Apache `DocumentRoot` to my home, but I get logically a forbidden page. I tried to add `www-data` user in my group, with the same result.

I would not prefer give full access to any user in my home.

So how should I proceed to let apache read my home dir?

```
$ ls -la /home | grep gael

drwxr-xr-x 44 gael    gael     4096 mars  17 22:30 gael

$ groups www-data;
www-data : www-data gael
```

The error log:

```
  [Tue Mar 17 22:43:06.592819 2015] [authz_core:error][pid 4572] [client 127.0.0.1:59677]
 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/gael/
```

apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/gael/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you can set the permissions for owner, a group and everyone else individually.

Comment: your image has no additional information to the`ls -lad /home/gael` line. anyhow what's the output of `groups www-data`; what's the configuration of your webserver; what's in the error-logs of your webserver?

Comment: and how is this question related to programming? [su] would be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the user running the webserver has full `read` permissions to all files they need to see. they will also require `execute` permissions for any directory they need to traverse into.

so it seems that you have added the `www-data` user to your own group, which should fulfill the above.

be aware, that a new group-membership does not take effect immediately: interactive users need to login again, a daemon needs to be restarted (thus: restart apache). the w32 way (just reboot) will also work.

btw, exposing your home via a webserver seems like a **bad** idea: anybody who can access the webserver (usually anybody on the same net) will be able to see your home-directory. make sure that you add extra security (password protection, encryption,...).

btw, did you know that the `~/public_html` directory is traditionally exported by your web-browser as `~<user>` (so if your login name is "gael" you can access this directory via `http://localhost/~gael/`). if the directory does not exist, just create it and make sure that you set its group to `www-data`. this is a much more secure way to share *some data* via the web.

Comment: I have rebooted, no change. See the edit, the dir have execution permission.

Comment: thank you for your cautions. That is what I want to be able to access to my files in my local network